# change textbox value with javascript codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, textbox

My View with javascript :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("asd").value = 'sdasdsad';
</script>
</head>

<body>
$atta = array(
    'id' => 'asd'
);
echo form_input($atta);
</body>
</html>
```

the result is, that my textbox is empty. What happened?

Comment: Can you post more code for your view. It's difficult to tell with the code you've provided

Comment: it's simple page, i have edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your did not enclosed your php scripts to php tags.

Why not try this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function() {
       document.getElementById("asd").value = 'sdasdsad';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="asd" >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your JavaScript is running before the element has been rendered. Do something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("asd").value = 'sdasdsad';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$atta = array(
    'id' => 'asd'
);
echo form_input($atta);
?>
</body>
</html>
```